Which course is more beneficial for studying undergraduate computer science: Multivariable Calculus or Number Theory
I want to major in computer science for my undergraduate degree. I want to take one of the mathematics courses offered by Stanford ULO (https://ulo.stanford.edu/mathematics). I am unable to choose between Multivariable Differential Calculus or Number Theory. Can someone please provide some insight on which one of these courses would me more useful for computer science(I do not have the option of taking both).

It should depend on what you want to pursue next and, more importantly, what you like most. For example, a course on multivariable differential calculus would enable you to quickly adapt to the optimization problems that are more prominent in almost any research or practical field. While a course on number theory would give you an edge in more theoretical fields such as cryptanalysis: Ref1, Ref2

Honestly I like both. I was going to choose calculus anyways. But I was wondering would learning number theory relate to algorithms learned in undergrad CS.
